# Getting project URI from Visual Studio Team Services/TFS

Tags: c#, tfs, build, visual-studio-2015, azure-devops

I'm trying to get build statistics data from our TFS Source Control to show how much builds were successful and how many failed in between certain dates, however I'm having a lot of trouble trying to extract this data. Currently the closest resource which comes close to what I'm after is: http://pascallaurin42.blogspot.co.uk/2012/05/tfs-queries-recent-builds-of-all-team.html

When running this query in Linqpad I get an authentication error because my URI is incorrect. Does anyone know where a URI is located, or how to get the URI, for Visual Studio Team Services?

Comment: Can you use the rest api for builds? https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/integrate/api/build/builds

Comment: Thank you so much @Jras! No amount of Googling got me to that page! This is exactly the kind of information I'm looking for, thank you :)